# Kotlin Recyclerview ItemClick to new Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have a problem. I can print a toast message when I click on any item in Recyclerview. But I want to switch to a different activity when clicked. Could you please help me in a very specific way? It is a very important project for me. The code blocks I wrote are as follows. Thanks in advance .

CustomersAdapter

class CustomersAdapter(private val companynameArray:ArrayList,private val companyoffArray:ArrayList, private val companyPhoneArray:ArrayList):
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomersAdapter.CustomerHolder>() {

```
class CustomerHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    var recycleCompanyName: TextView?=null
    var recycleOffName: TextView?=null
    var recycleOffPhone: TextView?=null


    init {
        recycleCompanyName=view.findViewById(R.id.recycleCompanyName)
        recycleOffName=view.findViewById(R.id.recycleOffName)
        recycleOffPhone=view.findViewById(R.id.recycleOffPhone)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {


        }


    }



}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomerHolder {
    val inflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_customer_row,parent,false)
    return CustomersAdapter.CustomerHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return companynameArray.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomerHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.recycleCompanyName?.text="Şirket Adı:"+companynameArray[position]
    holder.recycleOffName?.text="Şirket Yetkilisi :"+companyoffArray[position]
    holder.recycleOffPhone?.text="İrtibat No : "+companyPhoneArray[position]
    }
}
```

I did not specify the activity I want to go to. I would appreciate it if you could help as a method.

If it helps, I write the codes of the client class here.

class Customers : AppCompatActivity()

{

```
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

var companynameFB:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var companyoffFB:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var companyphoneFB:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var adapter :CustomersAdapter?=null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers)

    auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
     getDataFromFirestore()

    var layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager=layoutManager

    adapter= CustomersAdapter(companynameFB,companyoffFB,companyphoneFB)
    recyclerView.adapter=adapter
```

}

```
fun getDataFromFirestore(){

    db.collection("Customers")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->

        if(exception!=null){

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }else{

            if(snapshot!=null){

                if (!snapshot.isEmpty){

                    companynameFB.clear()
                    companyoffFB.clear()
                    companyphoneFB.clear()


                    val documents=snapshot.documents
                    for (document in documents){


                        val compname=document.get("compname") as String
                        val compoff=document.get("compoff") as String
                        val compphone=document.get("compphone") as String
                        val user=document.get("user") as String
                        val timeStamp=document.get("date") as Timestamp
                        val date=timeStamp.toDate()

                        companynameFB.add(compname)
                        companyoffFB.add(compoff)
                        companyphoneFB.add(compphone)

                        adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()



                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }



}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
```

val menuInflater=getMenuInflater()
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_customer,menu)

```
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    if(item.itemId==R.id.add){


        val intent= Intent(this,AddCustomers::class.java)
```

intent.putExtra("info","new")
startActivity(intent)

```
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starting a new Activity you need at least a context instance. And as is written in some other answers here, you could start the activity directly inside `ViewHolder` with View's context. But for better separations of responsibilities, I suggest you move your navigation to your `Fragment/Activity`, where all other navigations happen. That way you know at the look of `Activity/Fragment`, which navigations could be done from that screen, and you don't need to search for some hidden navigations that happen inside `Adapter` or `ViewHolder`. Also, if you need to perform `startActivityForResult`, then an instance of `Context` is not enough to do that. You need an `Activity` or `Fragment` instance for that and we have another reason to put all navigations there.

So you can do this like that:

**ADD LAMBDA TO ADAPTER CONSTRUCTOR:**

```
class CustomersAdapter(private val companynameArray: ArrayList,
private val companyoffArray: ArrayList, 
private val companyPhoneArray: ArrayList, 
private val onItemClick: () -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomersAdapter.CustomerHolder>() {
```

***NOTE***: put lambda as the last constructor parameter.

**ADD LAMBDA TO VIEWHOLDER CONSTRUCTOR:**

```
class CustomerHolder(view: View, 
    private val onItemClick: () -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
```

**MODIFY VIEWHOLDER CONSTRUCTOR CALL:**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomerHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_customer_row,parent,false)
    return CustomersAdapter.CustomerHolder(view, onItemClick) //Add onItemClick lambda instance from adapter here
}
```

**INVOKE LAMBDA ON CLICK:**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener {
    onItemClick()
}
```

**FIX ADAPTER CONSTRUCTOR CALL:**

```
val adapter = CustomersAdapter(companynameArray, companyoffArray, companyPhoneArray) {
    startActivity() // do your navigation here
}
```

Why did we place lambda as the last parameter of a constructor in our adapter? If the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses([SOURCE](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter)). And we did exactly that with the last junk of code above where we handle our navigation.

Comment: Thank you sir

Except for the last part, I did what I said. Where do I write the code block in the last part? (Fix adapter constructor call). Can you write the intent part fully?

Comment: I will need more information regarding that. What Activity do you want to open? Do you want to pass any additional data to the new activity? if yes, which data?

Comment: Thank you sir. I did as you said and succeeded. But is it possible that I can reach you for different questions?

Answer (score 0):

put your click listener inside `onBindViewHolder`  method

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomerHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.recycleCompanyName?.text="Şirket Adı:"+companynameArray[position]
    holder.recycleOffName?.text="Şirket Yetkilisi :"+companyoffArray[position]
    holder.recycleOffPhone?.text="İrtibat No : "+companyPhoneArray[position]

 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            // do what ever you want here
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity( /*your intent here*/)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.But holder not working this area

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : pass context here

```
class CustomersAdapter(val context:Context,private val 
companynameArray:ArrayList,private val 
companyoffArray:ArrayList, private val companyPhoneArray:ArrayList): 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomersAdapter.CustomerHolder>() {
```

step 2:

```
  itemView.setOnClickListener {
       val intent=Intent(context,yourActivity::java.class)
       startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. However, when I did what you said, I did not get a result. I encountered many errors like the following.

CustomersAdapter.kt: (30, 61): Name expected
CustomersAdapter.kt: (31, 46): Expecting ')'
CustomersAdapter.kt: (12, 36): Unresolved reference: Context
CustomersAdapter.kt: (30, 35): Unresolved reference: context
CustomersAdapter.kt: (31, 39): Unresolved reference: intent

Answer (score 0):

you need a **context** for intent so you can get it form the **activity** or **fragment** that are associated with this **adapter** and pass it to your intent or you can get it from any view in your inflated layout like this

```
 val context=holder.title.context
    val intent = Intent( context, EventDetail::class.java)
    context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Thank you sir.exactly where will I write this